# Use object in template part

Tags: php, loop, oop

I try to use a template part in my loop.

```
<?php
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    get_template_part( 'temp-parts/loop/blcnr_loop');
}
?>
```

In the template part I call the object

```
<?php 
echo $category->name; 
?>
```

But this gives me an error "**Trying to get property 'name' of non-object**".
Is there a solution for this?

I tried this

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $categoryData = array(
            'name' => 'theName'
        );
        get_template_part( 'temp-parts/loop/blcnr_loop',  NULL, $categoryData);
}
```

And this in the template part

```
echo $categoryData['name'];`
```

But this returns NULL

Comment: How are you getting the categories?  If you `var_dump( $categories );` is it an array of objects or just an array of `IDs/slugs/etc`.  Comment out `get_template_part()` and also try a `var_dump( $category );` and make sure that it's an object.

Comment: You can't use variables like that, you need to pass them somehow, there's a parameter in `get_template_part` for it

Comment: @TomJNowell 

I updated my question with some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As of WordPress 5.5](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/17/passing-arguments-to-template-files-in-wordpress-5-5/) you can pass variables to template parts by passing them in an array to the third argument of `get_template_part()`:

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    get_template_part( 'temp-parts/loop/blcnr_loop', null, [ 'category' => $category ] );
}
```

These variables will populate an `$args` variable accessible from the the template:

```
echo $args['category']->name;
```

Comment: Hi Jacob I saw this documentation on the Wordpress developement site. As you can see in my question returns the array NULL :-(

Comment: As my answer and the documentation says, the values are put into a variable `$args`. You need to use that.